# creating a class that holds generic delegates

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, delegates

I'm trying to create a class thats holds two (or more) generic delegates as properties. This way I can pass the object to a method and use only one parameter on that method. The problem is that I get a warning to specify a type, but I don't know the type yet. The whole point is to defer type declaration until the object gets instantiated.

Here's some **dummy code** dummy code to show what I want to do.

```
Public Function Method1()
     Dim _container as Container = new Container()
     _container.Property1 = //Here create delegate with type string
     _container.Property2 = //Here create delegate with type integer
     Method3(_container)
End Function

Public Function Method2()
     Dim _container as Container = new Container()
     _container.Property1 = //Here create delegate with type Integer
     _container.Property2 = //Here create delegate with type integer
     Method3(_container)
End Function

Public Function Method3(container as Container)
  //execute type specific code and the delegates
  //Throw exception when type is not supported (yet)
end Function

public Class Container
      Property Property1 as MyDel(of T)
      Property Property2 as MyDel(of T)
end Class

Public delegate function Mydel(of T)()
```

That's it. The point of this being that when adding new information/functionality to the system it is easy to create a new method called Method4, which uses arguments as needed (and of course create the method that will be executed as delegate).

I would like to put two delegates in one class because their is a connection between them and things belonging together should be put together in one class; just like a Person class can hold a name and address.

This code doesn't work, because Container needs a Type T, which means Method3 needs a specific type, but i can't do that because then I can't call Method3 with different arguments as I showed. I tried using a wrapper class, but a type specification is needed all the time.

I know you can do this

```
Public Property TestProp() As [Delegate]
    Get

    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As [Delegate])

    End Set
End Property
```

[source:http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=96800]

But that is not generic. What am I missing?

BTW, this is an optimization for code calling Method3 with two arguments. That seemed to work fine. Then I thought trying to use only one argument, which would make the system easier to understand.

My old code looks something like this:

```
Public function OldMethod1()
    Dim del1 as Mydel(of Integer) = AddressOf SomeMethod
    Dim del2 as MyDel(of String) = AddressOf SomeOtherMethod
    oldMethod3(del1, del2)
end Function

Public function OldMethod2()
    Dim del1 as Mydel(of String) = AddressOf AnOtherMethod
    Dim del2 as MyDel(of String) = AddressOf AgainSomeOtherMethod
    oldMethod4(del1, del2)
end Function

Public Function oldMethod3(del1 as Mydel(of Integer), del2 as Mydel(of string))
    //execute delegates
end Function

Public Function oldMethod4(del1 as Mydel(of string), del2 as Mydel(of string))
    //execute delegates
end Function
```

When reading this code I saw that it is only the type of the parameter the determines the execution flow. So if you can determine the subtype of the generic you know what to do. That seemed to be possible (use typeOf and or GetType), so the next thing to do is to create a generic parameter object that could be a substitute for 'del1' (I now realize I took it even took one step further and created the Container class to hold both the parameters).

Any answer in C# or VB.net will do. I use both.

Comment: It seems like Container is a 2-type generic (2 type arguments) and perhaps Method 3 should be as well (not as sure on this). You can't weakly type C#/VB, so I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps a set of sample calls would be useful?

Comment: I added some old code sample and changed some original code. I hope this better explains what I want ot accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little confusing, so this may not be an answer, but it's too long for a comment!  I think what you want to do is use `Action(Of T)` as the type for `Container.Property1` and `Container.Property2`.

Something like this (this will run in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) using Language: VB Program):

```
Sub Main

    Dim c1 = New Container(Of String, String)()
    c1.Property1 = AddressOf Method1
    c1.Property2 = AddressOf Method1
    Method3(c1)

    Dim c2 = New Container(Of String, Integer)()
    c2.Property1 = AddressOf Method1
    c2.Property2 = AddressOf Method2
    Method3(c2)

End Sub

Public Sub Method1(x As String)
    Console.WriteLine("Method1: {0}", x)
End Sub

Public Sub Method2(x As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("Method2: {0}", x)
End Sub

Public Sub Method3(Of T1, T2)(container as Container(Of T1, T2))
    Console.WriteLine("Method3 got {0}, {1}", GetType(T1), GetType(T2))
    ' Not sure how you would actually call the delegates
    If GetType(T1) = GetType(String) Then
        container.Property1.DynamicInvoke("Hello")
    ElseIf GetType(T1) = GetType(Integer) Then
        container.Property1.DynamicInvoke(123)
    End If
    If GetType(T2) = GetType(String) Then
        container.Property2.DynamicInvoke("World")
    ElseIf GetType(T2) = GetType(Integer) Then
        container.Property2.DynamicInvoke(456)
    End If
End Sub

Public Class Container(Of T1, T2)
    Public Property Property1 As Action(Of T1)
    Public Property Property2 As Action(Of T2)
End Class
```

This produces the following results:

```
Method3 got System.String, System.String
Method1: Hello
Method1: World
Method3 got System.String, System.Int32
Method1: Hello
Method2: 456
```

Comment: I'm not able to test this; I changed back to the old code, because this was only part of my solution. Anyway, as far as I can see this is what I was looking for. I will try this when I have time and get back when needed. Thanks.

Comment: If your reading this, could you elaborate a bit about the confusing part. I tried to be as specific as possible, also including some background idea's about the code I was trying to write. I would like to learn from this because I tried to be specific, but I obviously wasn't. I would like to know where I should have been more specific. We all know general questions will either get general answers, be downvoted or will not be answered at all. This question got downvoted which I think the question did not deserve (but that's just my opinion).

Comment: @Sigur Sorry - have been out for a few days.  I think the confusing part was just the generic-ness of the function and property names in your example code, but reading through again it doesn't seem that confusing this time (which could just be because I had worked through it before).  Sorry I can't be more specific/helpful!  I don't think your question deserves the down votes either - it's obvious you put a lot of effort into it, and comments to prompt for clarification of the question would be more productive than down voting.